# How to save inline-html in a new php file?

Tags: php, html, ajax, post, fwrite

I have some html code between two `<ul>` tags, that I want to save in an external file called `list-content.php`.

```
<ul class="list-content">
  <li> Here goes some content 1 </li>
  <li> Here goes some content 2 </li>
  <li> Here goes some content 3 </li>
  <li> Here goes some content 4 </li>
</ul>

<div class="save-button"></div>
```

With jQuery I get the content between the `ul` tags which I `POST` to a PHP file via AJAX.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.save-button').click(function(){
    var list_content = $(".list-content").html();
    console.log(list_content);

    var ajaxurl = 'save.php',
    data =  {'content': list_content};

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
      alert("Worked!");
    });
  });
});
```

I think until here it works perfectly!
But my `save.php` is not working as it should…
Basically I'm trying to write a file named `list-content.php` with the html between the `ul` tags…

```
<?php
$post_data = $_POST['content'];

if (!empty($post_data)) {
  $filename = 'list-content.php';
  $handle = fopen($filename, "w");
  fwrite($handle, $post_data);
  fclose($handle);
  echo $file;
}
?>
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Did you check the file ? It must be writing to the file. You are just echoing $file, which will not show you anything.

Comment: @Sameer Yup, the `list-content.php` file stays empty…

Comment: Try dumping $post_data to check if the data is really coming to php or not.

Comment: make sure fopen is enabled: `if (function_exists('fopen')) { ... }`  your code works for me